# After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered - swagger -json - post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am calling POST method from Swagger UI with the values in double quotes as per below, but getting an error. Check the sample data below and the response screenshot for the error.

```json
{
  "formFieldsModel": {
    "formsId": 1,
    "fieldValues": "[[{id: 1, lable: "Email"}]]"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well yes, that's not valid JSON. The double-quotes need to be escaped, e.g. `"[[{id: 1, lable: \"Email\"}]]"`. (Are you sure the value of `fieldValues` should be a string containing JSON, rather than a JSON array directly, btw?)

Comment: Error messages should be included as text in the description for easy reference - not as links to images

Comment: @JonSkeet how can I escape double quotes..is there anything I need to add in startup class or in action method

Comment: You escape the double quotes when *sending the request* - not in the code *receiving* the request. If you're sending the request in code, you should use a JSON formatter rather than hand-crafting it. If you're sending the request via a UI that lets you just put in the raw JSON, just add the backslash yourself. (I haven't used Swagger UI much myself - but I'd be surprised if it sends invalid JSON...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes from front end user will submit form and then I will get this request

Comment: Yes, but you've said you've observed this problem *from Swagger UI* - not from your own frontend. Please edit your question to be *much* clearer about what's generating this request. But fundamentally whatever is creating the request needs to create valid JSON.

Comment: Right now I am doing testing from swagger so I post in that way, once this API completed then from front end user will submit form and then this API will get called..